Avalonia Browser application not working after upgrading Avalonia packages
I upgraded the Avalonia packages from 11.0.6 to 11.2.2 because I needed to add a dependency that requires a minimum of 11.1.4
Now the browser project won't run. It gets to the Avalonia splash but not to any of the breakpoints.
Tried it in a simple out-of-the-template Avalonia cross-platform projects and get the same result. Runs at 11.0.6 but not at 11.2.2 nor even 11.0.10
In the debug output it shows this error:
Could not read source map for http://localhost:5001/dotnet.js: Unexpected 404 response from http://localhost:5001/dotnet.js.map:
MONO_WASM: Failed to load config file ./blazor.boot.json SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': Unexpected end of JSON input SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
In the AppBundle folder, the main.js file references the dotnet.js file as before at line 1.
import { dotnet } from './dotnet.js'
Anybody know what else I have to do for such an upgrade?
